# Magento2.2.2: UI Component Grid Filter Issue-Please explain getCollection function with excluded and selected how related with ui-grid?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, filter

**Magento2.2.2** UI Component Grid Filter Issue.

Please explain **getCollection** function with excluded and selected how related with **UI-grid**

```
\Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter

public function getCollection(AbstractDb $collection)
{
    $selected = $this->request->getParam(static::SELECTED_PARAM);
    $excluded = $this->request->getParam(static::EXCLUDED_PARAM);

    $isExcludedIdsValid = (is_array($excluded) && !empty($excluded));
    $isSelectedIdsValid = (is_array($selected) && !empty($selected));

    if ('false' !== $excluded) {
        if (!$isExcludedIdsValid && !$isSelectedIdsValid) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('Please select item(s).'));
        }
    }
    /** @var \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection $collection */
    $idsArray = $this->getFilterIds();
    if (!empty($idsArray)) {
        $collection->addFieldToFilter(
            $collection->getIdFieldName(),
            ['in' => $idsArray]
        );
    }
    return $collection;
}
```

here what is the selected and excluded parameter and how it related with our admin UI-grid?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: code edited @ChiragPatel

Comment: "SELECTED_PARAM" & "EXCLUDED_PARAM" are defined constant variables, when you filter in grid then it's check which input field value is  filled and give the collection based on that

Comment: when excluded value will come false?

Comment: Not filled input field value are come to false while submitting filter form, you get bot filled and not filled value.

Comment: Sorry not following you,Can you please explain briefly